# Covariance matrices and independency

Tags: probability, independence, covariance-matrix

If we have a diagonal covariance matrix does that guarantee independency?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, not in general. A covariance of zero between two random variables does not necessarily imply that they are independent. However, the statement is true if the variables are normally distributed.

Comment: In fact, zero covariance does not imply independence even for normally distributed variables. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#A_symmetric_example). Rather,  if two variables are from a multivariable normal distribution and are zero covariance, it implies independence.